# c++ classes within classes reading parent class

Tags: c++, class

So i am currently working on a small ant farm simulator type jobby and i have come across an issue.

first i have 4 classes i'll simplify them here or the code will be looong:

```
class Ant
{
// Ant's stuff
}

class AntArray
{
std::vector<Ant> Antarray; //a vector that has ants added with a function
}

class AntHill
{
//ant hill stuff
}

class AntHillArray
{
std::vector<AntHill> HillArray; //a vector that has hills added with a function
}
```

i have that and i have a function in the Ant class that moves the ant to a location, i would like to reference the location of the ant hill's coordinates and do an algorithm to determine where to move the ant to.

How do i reference the ant hill's data to then do this without defining it in the Ant class itself as say a home variable (i would like the ability for an ant to change allegiance so to say and just move it with a function later on.

Thanks, John

Comment: If each ant has always a ant hill, it belongs to, you could declare AntHill before and add a `AntHill &my_hill` reference to Ant.

Comment: @jofel ive just had a brilliant moment thanks to this comment, i have been assuming that there would be multiple ant arrays for each hill but i simply dont need this, 1 array for all ants, this is a very useful thing thanks =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have another class called AntRelocation that takes as input the Ant instance and the AntHill instance, calculates what location to move to, and then calls Ant.setLocation() to change the state of the Ant to the new location.

This way, you have two kinds of objects: Entity objects (like Ant, AntHill, etc...) and Interactor objects (like AntRelocation, AntKiller, ...) that run your "business logic" or your "use cases". The entity objects only have methods that are shared by multiple use cases and are intrinsic to the object, like an Ant might have a location, a size, a color.

But to determine how an ant should move, you need information that is not part of the Ant object. Here the Interactor object comes into play. It implements logic that brings together data from different sources, keeping the Entity objects clean.

The is a "use-case"-driven approach to object-oriented design. It keeps your entity objects simple and not depending on too much stuff, and it allows you to add use-cases to your system by adding Interactor objects, without enlarging the entity objects.

Comment: Could i also do this with a function? is there any advantage to either way of doing it?

Comment: Yes. You could do this with a function. I mean, if you have several functions that are small and all fall under the same general category of "AntAlgorithms", you could definitely package them as a class called "AntAlgorithms".

Comment: If a function is long, then you will want to divide it to smaller functions, and then it is good to tie them all together in one class.

Comment: I recommend to watch Uncle Bob's video on Clean Code, where he explains all of that. He says a function should be not longer than 6 lines, and I actually practice this. In particular, look at episode 3 on functions (https://cleancoders.com/category/clean-code)

Comment: Ah, this is brilliant, thanks ive never thought to do it this way, my old college lecturer always had the mindset that an entity class would encapsulate everything it was and did, a "humans breathe and are a certain age old" idea, thanks again this will help in future projects too :)

Comment: Actually, we've had bad experience after a long time of following that approach. For example, we had 3D surfaces, and they knew how to draw themselves, how to calculate collisions between themselves, etc... This meant that a surface depended on rendering libraries, complex geometric algorithms, and much more. When we wanted to then reuse this surface class in another project where only a small part of the functionality was needed, it became a nightmare. We eventually had to rewrite the class, and take away only a small part of it.